# Not able to pull "Short Description" Column from Table from SAP

Tags: java, sap-erp, sapjco3

I am trying to pull data from some tables from SAP using SAP JCo, but in the table, I am not able to pull the "Short Description" column using JCo. In GUI, I can see a Short Description Column with data in it.

Code I am using:

```
JCoDestination destination = JCoDestinationManager.getDestination("SAP-ECC");

destination.ping();
logger.debug("Connected with SAP System");
// Create function module call
JCoFunction function = destination.getRepository().getFunction("RFC_READ_TABLE");

// Set up function module parameters
JCoParameterList imports = function.getImportParameterList();
imports.setValue("QUERY_TABLE", "E101");
imports.setValue("DELIMITER", ",");

JCoParameterList tableOptions = function.getTableParameterList();

JCoTable dataTable = tableOptions.getTable("DATA");
JCoTable fieldsTable = tableOptions.getTable("FIELDS");
// Execute the function module call
function.execute(destination);
logger.debug("Function Executed");

System.out.println(dataTable);
System.out.println(fieldsTable);
```

Comment: Please show how you see the "Short Description" in SAP ECC, the fields around, add screenshot(s) if possible., and which fields you currently get in JCo. Note that descriptions are usually language-dependent and stored in a separate table.